# Cannot execute zip task in Phing on XP

Tags: php, windows-xp, phing

I'm using Phing to create build files, but I've noticed that it does not appear to be able to execute the zip task:

```
<target name="makeroot">
    <echo msg="Making directory Template" />
    <mkdir dir="./../Template" />
</target>

<target name="makefolders" depends="makeroot">
    <echo msg="Making folders within Template" />
    <mkdir dir="./../Template/class" />
    <mkdir dir="./../Template/function" />
    <mkdir dir="./../Template/include" />
    <mkdir dir="./../Template/script" />
    <mkdir dir="./../Template/style" />
</target>

<target name="build" depends="makefolders">
    <echo msg="Copying files to build directory..." />
    <copy file="./class/ErrorHandler.class.php" tofile="./../Template/class/ErrorHandler.class.php" />
    <copy file="./function/validate.func.php" tofile="./../Template/function/validate.func.php" />
    <copy file="./include/standard_form.inc.php" tofile="./../Template/include/standard_form.inc.php" />
</target>

<target name="dist" depends="build">
    <echo msg="Creating archive..." />
    <zip destfile="temp.zip" basedir="C:\Program Files\wamp\www\sites\Template">
            <include name="*" />
    </zip>
    <echo msg="Files copied and compressed in build directory OK!" />
</target>
```

The first two tasks execute as expected, but the last one doesn't. Any Phing gurus out there able to lend me a hand with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is with your path/fileset configuration.  This is what we use to package web2project using Phing.  The "packaging" directory is within the current working directory.

```
<zip destfile="web2project-${releaseName}.zip">
  <fileset dir="packaging/">
    <include name="**/**" />
  </fileset>
</zip>
```